# EmberJS Clarifications on bindings

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am testing my way with emberjs so I need some help with these terms and when is the best time use them:

On Views what are the following bindings:

1. controller:
2. controllerBinding:
3. ContentBinding
4. eventManger

What is the difference between each one of them? I hope we can start a discussion in order to create a blog post to help others as well.

Best,